# XR origin script goes missing

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, virtual-reality

XR origin script goes missing whenever I restart my Unity project. Due to this the VR camera system does not work properly with camera not following the commands. While the project is open the script is there and the project is working fine.

The script is missing in the scene, I have not applied the override yet.

[image]

Only the script refrence is present in the prefab.

[image]

No script present in the project.

[image]

Tried reimporting the packages but it did not fix the issue, The script is only missing from the project due to which it is not able to refrence it in the component.

Comment: Try searching `In Packages` ;) It is not in `Assets` as it is not something you wrote .. it comes from [XR CoreUtilities](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.core-utils@2.4/api/Unity.XR.CoreUtils.XROrigin.html)

Comment: It's not there also